# От slideDown полоски

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове slideDown появляются странные полоски. Когда форма открывается полностью - они пропадают. При slideUp их тоже нет.

css:

```
#cover-window-find {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
z-index: 55;
top: 61px;
display: none; 
}
```

js:

```
jQuery('#find-action').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
        jQuery('#cover-window-find').slideUp(600); 
        jQuery(this).removeClass('active'); 
    } 
    else {
        jQuery('#cover-window-find').slideDown(600);
        jQuery(this).addClass('active'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Лишний контейнер, покрывающий форму.